# Stop JavaScript from truncating leading 0

Tags: javascript

I normally use the following code to get PHP variables into JavaScript:

```
echo("var zipCode = " . $zipCode . ";");
```

This works fine but on zip codes that start with a 0 it is truncating it.

I am trying to figure out a way to keep the leading 0.

Any help would be great.

Thanks

Comment: Unless you intend to process it as a number (add, subtract etc.) then don't think of it as a number, treat it as a string.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make it a string then:

```
echo("var zipCode = '" . $zipCode . "';");
```

Notice the two `'` characters before and after the concatenating of `$zipCode`.

I'm sure `$zipCode` is a string in your PHP, but when you echo it, it doesn't include the quotes. That means your resulting Javascript would look like:

```
var zipCode = 01234;
```

And there's no reason to store it as a number (incorrect number, in this case, since it will think it's an octal number).

So by adding the `'` characters, the resulting Javascript becomes:

```
var zipCode = '01234';
```

And should be just fine with manipulating, since you should really only be doing string manipulations on a zip code anyways.

If, for whatever reason, you decide that you need the Number form of the zip code, you can use this in Javascript:

```
var zipCodeNum = parseInt(zipCode, 10);
```

The important part is the `, 10`, as this will force the conversion to be in base 10, ignoring any leading `0`s.

Comment: By use, zip codes are *not* numbers. You never do numeric calculations on them. They should always be strings.

Comment: @JonathanM Doesn't matter. If the OP or anyone wants to use them for calculations, they're welcome to, there's no reason to stop them. I included the conversion just in case, no reason not to

Comment: @Ian, yeah, wasn't down on that. Was just letting the OP know.